# How do we create GV files with non-overlapping subgraphs from a GV file?

Tags: python, graphviz

#### Graph

I am having a GV file containing 3 subgraphs:

1. `cluster_1`
2. `cluster_2`
3. `cluster_3`

Source of `Final_Graph.gv`:

```
digraph Final_Graph {
    graph [center=true rankdir=LR ratio=compress size="15,10"]
    a
    b
    c
    d
    a -> b [label = 1]
    a -> c [label = 2]
    a -> d [label = 3]
    b -> d [label = 4]
    c -> d [label = 5]

    subgraph cluster_1{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="A"
        a
        b
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_2{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="B"
        a
        b
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_3{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="C"
        c
        d
    }
}
```

Rendered:

[image: rendered GV]

#### Wanted

I am looking to create other GV files with subgraphs being non-overlapping (that is subgraphs with no similar nodes, so for this case, the first file could have clusters 1 and 3, and the second file could have clusters 2 and 3).

#### Code

I am using this function in Python to do this task:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
def draw_graph_combinations():

# Load the original graph
  G = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.read_dot("Final_Graph.gv")

# Create an empty dictionary to store the subgraphs
  subgraphs = {}
  

# Iterate over the edges of the graph
  for u, v, data in G.edges(data=True):
    label = data.get("label")
    if label not in subgraphs:
        subgraphs[label] = nx.DiGraph()
   

  for node in G.nodes:
    # Add the node to each subgraph
    for label, subgraph in subgraphs.items():
        subgraph.add_node(node)
        
  for label, subgraph in subgraphs.items():
    for edge in G.edges:
        subgraph.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

 # Get all combinations of subgraphs
  combinations = itertools.combinations(subgraphs.items(), len(subgraphs))

# Iterate over the combinations
  for i, subgraph_items in enumerate(combinations):
    combined_subgraph = nx.DiGraph()
    for label, subgraph in subgraph_items:
        combined_subgraph = nx.compose(combined_subgraph, subgraph)
    nx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot(combined_subgraph, f"combined_subgraph_{i}.gv")
```

#### Issue

However, when I run this function in Python, the files printed out only contains the nodes and edges of the original file, without the subgraphs being shown.

#### Question

Is there any method in Python to divide this GV file into other files with non-overlapping subgraphs?

Comment: Note that while your file is legal syntax, your intent is not allowed by dot, neato, or fdp.  **Clusters cannot share nodes.**  However, the underlying datastructure built by the parser does!  So, your goal can probably be accomplished in Python, but not by me (don't do Python).  I can probably write it in **gvpr** (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf), if that would help.

Comment: As for gvpr, I have looked into the document @sroush, but I am not sure that either we would need to run that on the command prompt or not.

Comment: Please clarify your question: Is there a version-restriction like 1.10 (from your update and the comment on my answer is seems so), what does overlapping mean by example, how should expected output files look like? Plus: What did you try, debug and where can we help?

Comment: I have posted my update in another thread @hc_dev: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206005/splitting-a-gv-file-to-other-files-with-subgraphs-having-no-similar-node-pytho, so I hope you could have a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use package [*PyGraphviz*](https://pypi.org/project/pygraphviz/) for reading, modifying, writing and rendering Graphviz graphs.

#### PyGraphviz

Prerequisite: `graphviz` binaries have to be installed on your system.
Install the Python package using pip:

```
pip install pygraphviz
```

See [Install — PyGraphviz 1.10 documentation](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html).

#### Removal of overlapping subgraphs

Note: Instead loading from source string, you can also pass a file-handle or file-name as parameter to constructor [`AGraph(filename='Final_Graph.gv')`](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/agraph.html?highlight=filename#agraph-class) or `AGraph('Final_Graph.gv')`.

```py
import pygraphviz as pgv
import itertools

s = '''digraph Final_Graph {
    graph [center=true rankdir=LR ratio=compress size="15,10"]
    a
    b
    c
    d
    a -> b [label = 1]
    a -> c [label = 2]
    a -> d [label = 3]
    b -> d [label = 4]
    c -> d [label = 5]
    subgraph cluster_1{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="A"
        a
        b
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_2{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="B"
        a
        b
    }
    
    subgraph cluster_3{
        color=lightgrey style=filled
        label="C"
        c
        d
    }
}'''


# print some information of the parsed graph 
def print_info(G):
    print(f"Graph '{G.get_name()}' has:")
    print(f"* {len(G.nodes())} nodes")
    print(f"* {len(G.edges())} edges")
    print(f"* {len(G.subgraphs())} subgraphs")


def combine_subgraphs(G):
    combinations = itertools.combinations(G.subgraphs(), 2)  # iterator returned
    pairs = list(combinations)  # store iterator results in a list
    return pairs
    

def overlapping(pair_of_subgraphs):
    left_nodes = pair_of_subgraphs[0].nodes()
    right_nodes = pair_of_subgraphs[1].nodes()
    shared_nodes = set(left_nodes).intersection(set(right_nodes))
    return shared_nodes


def remove_subgraph(G, subgraph_name):
    # the first file could have clusters 1 and 3
    G_copy = G.copy()  # Return a copy of the graph.
    G_copy.remove_subgraph(subgraph_name)  # Remove subgraph with given name.
    print(f"## Copy: without {subgraph_name}\n{G_copy.string()}")  # Return a string (unicode) representation of graph in dot format.
    return G_copy
    
    
G = pgv.AGraph(string=s)  # loading a graph from source string
print_info(G)

pairs = combine_subgraphs(G)

print(f"Searching for overlapps in {len(pairs)} combinations:")
for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):
    if overlapping(pair):
        print(f"{i}: Overlapped ❌️")
        left_name = pair[0].name
        right_name = pair[1].name
        print(f"Removing left subgraph: {left_name} ..")
        left_removed = remove_subgraph(G, left_name)
        #left_removed.write(f"without_{left_name}.dot")  # Write graph in dot format to file on path.
        print(f"Removing right subgraph: {right_name} ..")
        right_removed = remove_subgraph(G, right_name)
        #right_removed.write(f"without_{right_name}.dot")  # Write graph in dot format to file on path.
    else:
        print(f"{i}: Non-Overlapping ✔️")
print("Done.")
```

Output on console (tested with pygraphviz version 1.6):

```
Graph 'Final_Graph' has:
* 4 nodes
* 5 edges
* 3 subgraphs
Searching for overlapps in 3 combinations:
0: Overlapped ❌
Removing left subgraph: cluster_1 ..
## Copy: without cluster_1
digraph Final_Graph {
    graph [center=true,
        rankdir=LR,
        ratio=compress,
        size="15,10"
    ];
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        graph [color=lightgrey,
            label=B,
            style=filled
        ];
        a;
        b;
    }
    subgraph cluster_3 {
        graph [color=lightgrey,
            label=C,
            style=filled
        ];
        c;
        d;
    }
    a -> b   [label=1];
    a -> c   [label=2];
    a -> d   [label=3];
    b -> d   [label=4];
    c -> d   [label=5];
}

Removing right subgraph: cluster_2 ..
## Copy: without cluster_2
digraph Final_Graph {
    graph [center=true,
        rankdir=LR,
        ratio=compress,
        size="15,10"
    ];
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        graph [color=lightgrey,
            label=A,
            style=filled
        ];
        a;
        b;
    }
    subgraph cluster_3 {
        graph [color=lightgrey,
            label=C,
            style=filled
        ];
        c;
        d;
    }
    a -> b   [label=1];
    a -> c   [label=2];
    a -> d   [label=3];
    b -> d   [label=4];
    c -> d   [label=5];
}

1: Non-Overlapping ✔️
2: Non-Overlapping ✔️
Done.
```

To save removal-results to files uncomment the respective write-lines.

Comment: I have tried your newest version of the code, but as you see from this documentation of copy in PyGraphviz, this method does not add subgraphs (https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/agraph.html#pygraphviz.AGraph.copy), so I got ```KeyError: Subgraph cluster_1 not in graph``` in my case. So do you have any other ideas for copying the GV file?

Comment: But otherwise, I have looked to your ideas about finding overlapping subgraphs, and they are really great!

Comment: Well.. I used pygraphviz v. 1.6. My ideas for copying the GV file: `G_copy = AGraph(string= G.string() )`.

Comment: Alright, I got the same solution as you now, thank you! I just feel bad that I did not get that idea sooner. Also, I am sorry for making you feel annoying with my questions, that's just because I want to give a more simple example for my problem (getting non-overlapping subgraph) and don't know that it is not applicable for my case.